# Ubuntu Server startup partition not selectable in BIOS menu

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios

I just installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.03 with two disks like this:

```
Disk model: ST4000LM024-2AN1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7010D0D6-B307-4FF0-BCD8-434932C089F2

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814033407 7814031360  3.7T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000LM024-2AN1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 34704922-427B-4EF0-86D0-C0652819C79B

Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096  251662335  251658240  120G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  251662336 7814033407 7562371072  3.5T Linux filesystem


blkid
/dev/sdb1: UUID="dace6e49-5297-4a1a-8517-0e4fce045ce4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="34ea091c-d4c0-4b06-8df0-b5f46a82de43"
/dev/sda2: UUID="43c6108c-2843-4c85-86ba-3a9cc74fb006" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="843e7636-011d-4b7f-a972-633a5f64ad28"
/dev/sda3: UUID="d7388b54-3437-4466-a568-c2e3e20443ca" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2f4bf77e-c09d-486d-a7f4-00db4f8b1316"
```

ubuntu server is on `sda2`.
all is working fine, except when booting the system it always tells me to enter BIOS for setup. both hard drives are available as boot options, but no startup partitions are offered to setup.

I can manually choose the correct disk `34704922-427B-4EF0-86D0-C0652819C79B` as startup override and it boots correctly from there.

Where did I go wrong with my setup and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the disks are GPT partitioned, but your system uses legacy BIOS, not UEFI. As per
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_(GPT)_specific_instructions:

The BIOS Boot partition GUID should be 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649 (check blkid). If it is, install GRUB manually:

```
# grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
```

Then make the grub config:

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If the GUID is different, you could try changing it. A few ways are described in https://www.simplified.guide/linux/disk-uuid-set. I've not done this myself, but at least this page does not mention losing any data during the process.

Comment: it looks like no partition has that GUID. I updated the question accordingly. Do you think I can just create a new MBR partition on disk `sda (sda4?)`. Then clone `sda2`to `sda4` and it should be able to boot from that in BIOS?

Comment: and what is `sda1 BIOS boot` for then?

Comment: /sda is the boot disk, /sda1 is the /boot partition, and grub will install itself where the OS shows /boot is, in your case /boot partition. Personally I would follow the Arch Wiki instructions - AFAIK they're usually very good and on point.

Comment: I have found that I must be running UEFI. But linux shows I am running BIOS. I have posted a new question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1674637/linux-shows-i-am-using-bios-when-my-motherboard-runs-uefi