# Linux shows I am using BIOS, when my motherboard runs UEFI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios, uefi

I ran into some boot problems on my [ubuntu server installation](https://superuser.com/questions/1674212/ubuntu-server-startup-partition-not-selectable-in-bios-menu).

Linux version 5.4.0-81-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-052) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04))

[GPT partition not showing up in BIOS/UEFI]

I have now realised that my [ASUS Maximus VII Impact is running on UEFI, not BIOS](https://rog.asus.com/sg/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-vii-impact-model/), so the GPT partition should show up in the selection. But when I check if I run BIOS or UEFI: `ls /sys/firmware/efi` 
I get: `ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi': No such file or directory` and `dmesg | grep "EFI v"` returns nothing, indicating I dont run UEFI.

So how comes I am booting from BIOS when my BIOS/UEFI (whatever it is I am looking at) screen, has a modern, mouse operable interface? And how should I proceed so linux boots from UEFI?

Comment: What distribution are you running. Currently Fedora and Ubuntu use UEFI and Secure Boot.   ...... https://itvision.altervista.org/best-linux-distro-this-year.html#:~:text=Currently%20two%20leading%20Linux%20distributions,need%20to%20download)%20and%20Ubuntu.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Guys, have a look at the first posting. There's an entire relevant story he left out from this posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So how comes I am booting from BIOS

Most UEFI systems (except for some extremely new ones) have a "Compatibility Support Module" (aka "CSM mode" aka "Legacy boot") which allows them to emulate the traditional BIOS boot process. When an OS is booted in this mode, the EFI System Partition is not used (the disk's bootsector is booted instead) and the OS cannot access the UEFI-specific interfaces (hence no /sys/firmware/efi).

The firmware settings screen will have an option to disable the compatibility mode and enforce native UEFI boot only. (The option may be named in several different ways, but it *will be* present, because Microsoft requires it as part of Secure Boot support.)

However, having the CSM enabled *does not prevent* an OS from being booted in native UEFI mode – it just makes *both* modes available. Typically in such systems, when CSM is enabled, the <kbd>F8</kbd> boot menu will show both "legacy" BIOS-mode and "native" UEFI-mode items at the same time.

- For example, if the same Ubuntu installation USB stick is compatible with both BIOS-mode boot and UEFI, then it will show up twice. This often leads to people choosing the wrong item – booting the USB stick in BIOS mode – out of habit, and the OS installer will accordingly prepare the system disk to be booted in BIOS mode as well, despite the firmware being UEFI-capable.
- This is not the only cause of BIOS-style OS installations on UEFI-capable computers, but it's fairly common. Another common cause is programs used to write an .iso image to a USB stick – some of them insist on re-arranging the image's boot process in their own way, and this often ends up with the USB stick only being BIOS-compatible even if the original image had UEFI support. Thanks to CSM being enabled, the USB stick will still *work* and the user won't realize anything missing.

So you're booting in BIOS mode because 1) the firmware is capable of doing so, and 2) the OS on this particular disk was installed this way.

> my BIOS/UEFI (whatever it is I am looking at) screen, has a modern, mouse operable interface?

The interface has very little to do with the firmware type. (Or maybe "correlation doesn't imply causation"?) Yes, modern, mouse-operable interfaces are common nowadays, and so are UEFI firmwares, but neither actually implies the other – text-mode setup screens are just as common in UEFI systems, while some manufacturers used to have mouse-operable BIOS interfaces 30 years ago.

> And how should I proceed so linux boots from UEFI?

If the OS isn't installed yet, or you're fine with reinstalling it:

1. Go to your firmware settings and make sure to disable "CSM" or set the boot mode to "native" or "UEFI only" (or whatever it is called in ASUS firmwares).

   (With Ubuntu, you can even enable Secure Boot – this will result in UEFI boot being mandatory as a side effect.)
2. Reinstall the OS.

If the OS is already installed and you want to keep it:

1. Manually create an EFI System Partition. Mount it at /boot/efi (to match what Ubuntu does).

   If you don't have any more unallocated space, shrink the root partition. The EFI System Partition doesn't have to be at the beginning, but it does need to be at least 100 MB (so the existing 1 MB "BIOS boot" partition won't do).
2. Install the correct GRUB2 package (e.g. `grub-efi-amd64`) and grub-install the bootloader again. You don't need to specify "/dev/sda" this time.

   ```
   grub-install --target=x86_64-efi
   ```

   You'll probably need to re-run `update-grub` after this.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly, that following those last steps would save my current installation? Create `sda4`, make it GPT, install grub, wipe BIOS bootsector of `sdX`. Where sdX is what? `sda1`or `sda4`?

Comment: If you determine through /sys that the system is correctly booting in UEF mode, then you can skip that step and keep the bootsector as it is, it'll just be ignored in UEFI boot. That said, the bootsector is at the beginning of the whole disk i.e. `sda` itself. _(It's the 1st stage of GRUB, which then jumps to sda1 where the 2nd stage is.)_

Comment: i'll give that a shot. If I mess something up i'll have to take to long way around and re-setup everything anyway on the weekend

Comment: Since partitioning is gpt, you can easily convert just by first adding ESP - FAT32, with boot,esp flags, if using gparted and reinstalling grub. But ESP must be in the first 2GB(?), so cannot be at end of your large drive. You uninstall grub-pc and install grub-efi-amd64. That also should add entry into fstab to mount ESP.

Comment: Great explanation! Squirreled away in my secret "keep this in mind" -notebook :-)

Comment: @oldfred: The ESP can be anywhere on the disk. Various ~2TB (very unlikely GB) limitations come either from the MBR partition table format, or from the BIOS-mode disk access APIs used by bootsector bootloaders, neither of which should apply to UEFI-mode boot process from a GPT disk.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding now.

Your partitioning shows a separate /boot partition, with type BIOS. As per the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_(GPT)_specific_instructions) page I linked earlier, this indicates the installation was made useing GPT partitioning table for a system with legacy BIOS. Since it was made this way, /sys/firmware/efi doesn't exist, and dmesg can't find anything about EFI either.

---

Misunderstanding snipped out

---

Since this is a new installation, I would suggest that you simply forget trying to fix this, and just re-do the installation from the start. The only way I can imagine this happens is that something went wrong the first time. It's happened to everyone.

Verify that your BIOS is set to UEFI mode, not Legacy, and Secure Boot is disabled. Read and follow the Ubuntu Server installation instructions.

That should get you up'n running with the minimum hassle.

Comment: I agree. Of course I wanted to avoid it when possible. I already have a lot of data on those drives and it will be a bit of a hassle. But necessary. I'll check if it reboots correctly before moving on this time. thanks for the help

Comment: A sec..........

Comment: Based on the partitioning, it looks like the boot is in sda1, system in sda2, and sda3 and sdb are data drives. Is that correct? If yes, you can just use the space taken by sda1 and 2. In this case Linux is a bit more forgiving than Windows. Of course if sdb has enough free space, you could move all the data you want to save there to keep it safe.

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: Don't mix up the _partition type GUID_ (which is discussed in Wikipedia, and is assigned from the list) and the _partition GUID_ (which is shown in the blkid dump as "PARTUUID" and is normally random) -- they're two separate fields in a GPT. The "UUID" field is also separate (it comes from the filesystem, not the partition table). In short it's fine for both UUID= and PARTUUID= to be completely different from the 21686... GUID in Wikipedia, and OP's `fdisk -l` output actually shows the correct type-GUID, although it is translated to a name ("BIOS boot").

Comment: Thanks, @user1686, I indeed did! Live and learn :-)